# How to wait for all callables to finish executing before proceeding?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, future, callable

I have the following code hashed out:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Long> {
    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}

public class MyController {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executos.newCachedTreadPool();

    public Long concurrentDoStuff() {
        List<MyCallable> workers = makeWorkers();

        List<Long> allResults = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for(MyCallable worker : workers) {
            Future<Long> workerResults = executor.submit(worker);

            try {
                allResults.add(workerResults.get());
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                // Handle...
            } catch(ExecutionException ee) {
                // Handle...
            }
        }

        // Question: how do I pause here and wait for all workers to finish?
    }
}
```

After the `for`-loop, I want to wait for all workers to finish before proceeding any further. What's the best/safest/most-efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to submit all your jobs first, then wait for their results. In your code, you wait for each result before sumitting the next jobs, which defeats concurrency.

Comment: +1 @RalfH - you should keep a list of futures, and don't dereference them until you've submitted all tasks.

Comment: Also, you should copy/paste your code. You have typos in the above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must shut the Executor down with `shutDown` and then wait until all jobs have been processed with `awaitTermination`.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf H (+1) - where would I place these 2 calls?

Comment: Actually, you might want to use a `CompletionService`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

- Initialize it with the number of workers
- Pass a reference to the latch in the worker constructor
- When the worker is done, call `countDown`
- Call `await` in the main thread and it will block until the workers are done.

This is a more general-purpose solution than using methods on the executor service.

Comment: This is a nice alternative.

Comment: Thanks @Alex (+1) - how does this approach fair differently than the `shutdown`/`awaitTermination` strategy recommended by others? Is it more efficient? Safer? Thanks again!

Comment: it is neither more efficient nor safer, it just introduces another concurrency object. As it is, the Executor is perfectly capable of managing its completion status using shutdown and awaitTermination. If you get() all your Futures anyway, you make sure they are completed, too. So if you get() your last Future, you know the Executor terminated.

Comment: @RalfH One advantage is that there is no need to shutdown the executor service.

Comment: But if you know the number of workers, you can just count down after each successful get(). The concurrent nature of CountDownLatch does not help any more than that.

Comment: Use of a countdown latch would allow you to re-use the executor service for other tasks at the same time. CountDownLatch is also useful for coordinating different asynchronous tasks - e.g. make sure job A is finished before job B begins, both of which are asynchronous. It might or might not be overkill in this situation, but it's an extremely useful tool to have in your toolbox.

Comment: OK, for multipurpose Executors it will help. But even then it is better to put the Futures in a collection and iterate calling get() later, since we want to use the results anyway.

Comment: What about threads which terminate abnormally? e.g. throw an uncaught exception?

Comment: @einpoklum putting the call to countDown in a finally block would account for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can call:

```
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE , TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

This will wait (almost) indefinitely for the tasks to complete.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan Jones (+1) - where would I place these 2 calls?

Comment: this will wait a long time, but not as long as you might think. The amount will be converted to nanoseconds first and overflow.

Comment: place these calls after you submitted all jobs.

Comment: Thanks again, but now I'm confused. If I call them after I submit all jobs, how can I then access each worker's results? Can you provide me with some pseudo-code? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: for accessing the Callables/Futures results using get(), it does not matter where these results are produced (be it an Executor or any other Thread), so you can get() them independently. The only thing you must be careful about is that the thread blocks on get(), therefore *another* thread must call() the Callable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy method.

```
ExecutorService.invokeAll(List<Callable> callables);
```

It will return `List<Future>` objects so that you can get the returned objects of all your individual `call()` methods.

You can get the instance of `ExecutorService` by calling `Executors.new....()`